# C++ Empty Angle Brackets in function returning Template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, return

In a chunk of libtorch (C++ PyTorch) code [here](https://krshrimali.github.io/Custom-Data-Loading-Using-PyTorch-CPP-API/), I saw a weird piece of C++ syntax that I'd never seen before:

```
Example<> get(size_t index);
```

This defines a function `get` which returns what exactly? What is `Example<>`?

Does this simply mean that it can return `Example<T>` for any type `T` and it's kind of like `auto`?

Also, for future reference, is there a name for classes like `Example<int>` (Something like templated classes perhaps?) to disambiguate them from other classes which were not created via templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the [declaration of `Example`](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/structtorch_1_1data_1_1_example.html#exhale-struct-structtorch-1-1data-1-1-example),

> ```
> template<typename Data = Tensor, typename Target = Tensor>
> STRUCT Example
> ```

You'll find it has two template parameters with [default template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Default_template_arguments), then `Example<>` refers to the instantiation as the default template arguments are specified, i.e. same as `Example<Tensor, Tensor>`.

Comment: So then to be more explicit, you could rewrite ```Example<> get(size_t index);``` as ```Example<Tensor, Tensor> get(size_t index);
```, right?

Comment: @JacKeown Yes, they're the same exactly.